# From Cloud Function to on-prem SQL Server, how do I make a secure connection (SSL/TLS) using pymssql

Tags: python, sql-server, google-cloud-platform

From other resources, I know I have to install FreeTDS for this to work. But in cloud function, as it is serverless, I cannot install.

Please any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this previous StackOverflow question, [pymssql package does not work with lambda in aws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37566890/pymssql-package-does-not-work-with-lambda-in-aws), provide any guidance?

Comment: Try  Cloud Run??

Answer (score 1):

There is a [publicissue](https://issuetracker.google.com/142821838) as Feature Request that allow cloud Function to access publicly route-able on-prem resources via their Serverless VPC Connector. Feel free to post there should you have any additional comments or concerns regarding the issue.

Comment: In cloud function, to make a secure connection, I need FreeTDS, which i cannot install. We have moved to cloud run. Thanks!